# Angled headings in CSS

Tags: css

Does anyone have any ideas to achieve this angled heading effect with CSS only?

[image: Angled heading]

The box shadow shouldn't be a problem using a generator like [this](https://css3gen.com/wp-content/cache/all/box-shadow/index.html), but I'm unsure on the angled edges - perhaps CSS3's transform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write this:

```
h1{
    font-size:24px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px;
}
h1:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    background:red;
    z-index:-1;
    -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
   -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
    box-shadow:3px 3px 0 0 #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 0 0 #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 0 0 #000;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RP356/

Comment: You don't have the minimum needed prefixes, put this code in http://prefixr.com/ and see what you get.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with just transform:skew():

```
transform:skew(-30deg,0);
-ms-transform:skew(-30deg,0); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:skew(3-0deg,0); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:skew(-30deg,0); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:skew(-30deg,0); /* Opera */
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/XeG4N/).

P.S. However keep in mind the “Heading” text and the skewed part have to be separate elements to avoid affecting the text too.

(In case the text is a child, you could set it straight using the opposite transformation: `transform:skew(30deg,0)`.)

Comment: This works great, thanks! The CSS for the child element is especially useful - I was wondering why `transform:skew(0,0)` wasn't working!

Difficult to determine what is the best solution really. Is there any benefit using this technique over the psudeo element one?

Comment: @alecrust yes. The pseudo element method is better, because it don't effect your semantic. This code works, but has not a good semantic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is transform. Following css does it for -20 degrees. and a white shadow

```
.box {
   -moz-transform: scale() rotate(0deg) translate(0px, px) skew(-20deg, deg);
   -webkit-transform: scale() rotate(0deg) translate(0px, px) skew(-20deg, deg);
   -o-transform: scale() rotate(0deg) translate(0px, px) skew(-20deg, deg);
   -ms-transform: scale() rotate(0deg) translate(0px, px) skew(-20deg, deg);
   transform: scale() rotate(0deg) translate(0px, px) skew(-20deg, deg);

   -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 5px #ffffff;
   -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 5px #ffffff;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 5px #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this will also skew any contents of the div as well as the box. So any content will need to be a seperate div. It also doesn't work in IE and really doesn't need the extra parameters of `scale() rotate(0deg) translate(0px, px)` just the `skew`

Comment: yes that's right, I just like to have all parameters in, to make possible changes easier. That it don't works in IE is given for most of CSS3. The question was about the box. That if you don't want the content skewed, you need to put it in another container should be clear I think

Comment: Many thanks for this. It appears I can straighten the child element (in this case a `<a>` within a `<h1>`) by applying `transform:skew(20deg,0)` (and the other vendor prefixes).

Now I'm trying to determine which is the best solution, this one or the psudeo element one posted by @sandeep

Answer (score 1):

In order to @SvenBieder answer, it is better to use something like this:

```
body {
    background: #ddd;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* In CSS3 it is ::before, but IE doesn't support this */
h1:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -5px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #555;

    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 3px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 3px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 3px #ffffff;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/fjPbr/1/

---

It's better because it don't skew the content and it has less code.

Comment: I think you got in here just after @sandeep. Thanks for the response though!